# Making requests after logging in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to apologise upfront for a noob level question.

I am working on an e-commerce project where I am making a bunch of requests to Django from REST. These requests are as follows,

1. GET/PUT/POST request related to fetching/updating/onboarding products
2. POST request for login/logout
3. GET/PUT request related to cart details
4. GET/POST/PUT requests for address related queries etc.

Since a lot of these requests are user specific (i.e. my onboarded products/my addresses/my cart data) **I want to somehow manage identify customer from the request without actually passing the customer id**. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want to know the user making the request right? Can you please share how you authenticate user? And if you can also share part of your code

Comment: I am currently passing customer id along with the request. I can't share my code because of privacy reasons at my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using django's built in authentication, `request.user` should give you the user making the request. (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#user)

If you're using your own authentication mechanism, you can write a custom authentication class (inherit from the base authentication class, override the `authenticate` method) and use it in the viewset / view. (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyCustomAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        custom_token = request.META.get('HTTP_CUSTOM_TOKEN')
        # get user from your db using custom_token and your authentication logic
        if user:
            return user, True
        return CustomAnonymousUser, False

class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [MyCustomAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # API logic here: use request.user to get content
        return Response(content)
```